# Find and replace exact word in long string

Tags: javascript

Below is my string :

```
api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}
```

**Search Term :**  Node-1

**Replace with :** Learning

**Expected output :**

```
api/Learning/{Learning}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}
```

Now here the problem is Node-1 is matching with other Node-1-1 also but I want exact word matching and replacement.

I have tried lots of options but none of them is working for me.

```js
 function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
    }

    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
    
    console.log(replaceAll('api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}','Node-1','Learning'));
    
    
    var  replaceStr = 'Node-1';
    console.log( 'api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}'.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+replaceStr+"\\b","gi"),"Learning"));
    
    console.log( 'api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}'.replace(/\bNode-1\b/g,'Learning'));
```

**Update :**  This question is not duplicate as my first answer is taken from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) only  which is not working with my input case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Liam Please see that i have tried something and not just blindly posted here.I might have miss the link of what you have showed in your comment that doesnt mean i have not shown my efforts and i have taken answer from the reference only of what you have shared which is not working in my scenario.Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```js
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str + '(?![-])';
}

console.log(replaceAll('api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}', 'Node-1', 'Learning'));
```

It searches every `str` occurence not followed by **'-'**. You can add other characters not to match if you want inside the character set.

Comment: Sorry but where to use this i mean from my 3 methods in which method i should use this?

Comment: Ok upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but i didnt understand your answer and last last("You can add other characters not to match if you want inside the character set")

Comment: I changed your regex generation to match the string given to `escapeRegExp` not followed by the **-** character. I also noticed you that you can add other characters to exclude inside the regex character set (ie. `[-]`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

try this regex `^(?!.*Node-1\(?!-1))\w+.*`

You can see it in action [here](http://regexr.com/3g6s8)

**EDIT**

So your code would be :

```
var str = 'api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}';
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp("Node-1\(?!-1)","gi"),"Learning"));
```

A working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fua3f7e/)

Comment: Sorry but what is the code and i cant see the output also

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I just posted the regex. check my edit!@Learning

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one fixes your problem:

```
var a = "api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}";

var arr = a.split("/");

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

    var word = arr[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z1-9- ]/g, "");
    if (word=="Node-1"){
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace("Node-1", "Learning");
    }
}

newString = arr.join("/");
console.log(newString);
```

check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8v0xt98/

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the **all-but-not** expression

```
console.log('api/Node-1/{Node-1}/Node-1-1/{Node-1-1}'.replace(new RegExp("Node-1[^-]","gi"),"Learning"));
```